# what does the highend OBD2 scanner offer?

Tags: obd-ii, scan-tool, flash-programing

I just want to clear some misconceptions that i have about the obd2 scanning tools :

- Is the difference between the high/low-end scanners is the software only?
- Do the highend use more connection wires on the OBD port ( so they access special functions )?
- Are the highend devices specific to a manufacturer?( so a good one will only work one brand )
- Can the highend scanner read more PID codes? ( not about giving an explanation of the fault code )
- Can highend scanner reprogram the ECU?

***why I'm asking :*** I have a Delphi DS150E scanner and I use it on three cars : Hyundai Tucson ,Mitsubishi L200 Sportero and Nissan Pathfinder on the L200 i could do some advanced stuff like switching ON/off the fuel injector while on the other two all i can do is read/clear the PID codes.

***note:*** *I know i should be asking one question at a time but these are all sub-question and fall under the main one*

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the functions and data for a given vehicle you need the OEM scanner. $$$  No generic scanner will cover all the functions and at times the data is missing or wrong. Several brands of clones are available.
They all use the same port and communication protocol is determined by the onboard computer so no, they do not access different pins in the connector. Generic OBD2 has a very limited PID set that varies by year with more added as the years went by. OEM units will access all the PID's for that vehicle plus all the other available computers. There all always many more PID's on the OEM and in newer vehicles hundreds more.
Reprogramming requires subscriptions to the OEM sites that have costs.
I am not familiar with your Delphi. I use two OEM scanners
 daily and have clones that purport to be identical but are not.
A place for all the OEM scanners.  http://www.nastf.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=1

Source: 30 years automotive diagnostics